# How to get method name in method decorator

Tags: javascript

I have this decorator:

```
export function foo(prop: string = '') {
    return function (target, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        Reflect.defineMetadata(some-key, prop, target.constructor, descriptor.value.name)
    }
};

@foo('foofoo')
async someFunction() :Promise<number> {
}
```

when i run it in node all fine, but when i trying to run in the browser, the descriptor.value.name is empty.(Instead of 'someFunction')

So, there is  another way to get the method name in the browser?

Comment: `defineMetadata` is not a `Reflect` method.

Comment: reflect-metadata

Comment: Not sure what the previous comment intends to convey. Browsers do not have a built-in `Reflect.defineMetadata` method, see [`Reflect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect). What is the purpose of the `defineMetadata`?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata , but what is matter for the question ?

Comment: Have you tried using the code at the github link?

Comment: just ignore the "reflect" line, i need the name of the function.

Comment: Do you mean a function defined as a property value of `target`?

Comment: I hope that now  is more clearly ...

Comment: `propertyKey` should be the property name, no? Yes, the function object that is defined as a method isn't necessarily named, especially if you are using a transpiler.